# Yii2 view и шаблон

Tags: yii2

У меня образовался очень большой код вью, что бы его сделать более читабельным
я часть кода я выношу в другой файл и потом вставляю его во вью.

В основном вью я подключаю модель `use app\models\options;`
потом ниже по коду я подключаю файл(шаблон) таким образом:

```
<?php require '../library/site_templ/event/add_event_editor.php'; ?>
```

В этом шаблоне возникает ошибка:

> Class 'options' not found

Получается вынеся часть кода, я должен также и выносить и объявления всех моделей и т.д.?
Ведь я же объявил модель в родительской вью, зачем его подключать еще раз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правило, к модели обращаются из контроллера, присваивают ее переменной и передают эту переменную в файл представления. Если файл представления получается большим, скорее всего там возникла какая-то логика, которой не должно быть. Обычно файлы представления получают данные и отображают их, а все условия получения данных в методах моделей.

Если файл представления все равно большой, вероятно, есть смысл создать виджет, в который вынести часть кода для отображения данных.

Кто продолжает использовать `require` в файлах представлений, тот идет читать документацию по фреймворку еще раз. Есть `render, renderPartial, renderFile`.

[Подробно о видах и шаблонах.](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-views)

Comment: слишком большая верстка у страницы добавления события, много инпутов, списков и т.д. код адаптивный естественно и это еще создает путаницу. Виджет не решение, сколько мне их 5-10 написать нужно, да и зачем если это в основном верстка.

Вот и консультируюсь как это лучше сделать, пока делаю c require.
А как работают шаблонизаторы в Yii?

Comment: @SergeyP Добавил ссылку в ответе

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В каждой вьюхе нужно прописывать свои юзы `use app\models\options`;
Так же можно передать во вьюху модель из другой вьюхи

*view1.php*

```
$this->render('view2', ['model' => $model]);
```

*view2.php*

```
echo $model->property;
```